# Модуль Broadcom-wl в ядре Linux

Tags: linux, manjaro, ядро

Собственно вопрос. Природа мой ноут одарила "чудесной" wlan картой Broadcom 43227. На ней прилично "заводиться" драйвер broadcom-wl (или просто wl). Этот драйвер, по-идее, есть в самом ядре Linux, проблема лишь в том, что он не заводиться автоматически. Я бы с удовольствием его "завел" с помощью modprobe, да вот не могу найти сам файл wl.ko в системе. Ищу примерно тут:

`/lib/modules/версия_ядра/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/`

Почему я решил, что он есть в ядре? Да потому что при установке без подключение к инету Manjaro с параметром "несвободные драйвера" он подхватился. И это верно, это приоритетный драйвер. Кто знает как его ручками завести? Надоело вечно за проводом бегать.

Comment: http://tsya.ru

> приоритетный

ПРОПРПИЕТАРНЫЙ

Comment: лучше бы по делу помогли.

Comment: Как насчёт их brcmsmac (PCI) / brcmfmac (SDIO)?

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, broadcom-wl можно установить из AUR c помощью [yaourt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yaourt_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) -S broadcom-wl, или же собрать модуль ядра из  исходников: http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_248.tar.gz.